# Web api Data Annotations cause 500 server error when passed

Tags: asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, facebook-c#-sdk

I am creating a web api project and want to add validation to my model, so I added a DataAnnotation attribute.

I then tested the project by trying to pass my object from a separate mvc project. I recieved a 500 server error.

Removing the DataAnnotation allows me to pass the object successfully. Why?

I have looked at a couple of tutorials such as [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1191/aspnet-web-api-model-validation-custom-action-filter) and [this](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api), they show how to handle validation errors, but this has not helped.

**UPDATE**

Removing the data annotation from MyProperty in Class1, solution B (but leaving it on the class in solution A) means values can be passed successfully! Is this a problem with deserilazing the object? If so how do I solve it?

B = My web service reciving the object

A = My mvc project sending the object

**my code to send the resquest**

```
public class Class1
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "MyProperty  value is required")]//remove this line to make it work
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public Class2 MyOtherProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}


    async Task<string> Test2()
    {
        var form = new Class1();
        form.MyProperty = 123;
        form.Class2 = new Class2();

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58814/api/");
            var post = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<Class1>("Values", form);
            var putt = await client.PutAsJsonAsync<Class1>("Values", form);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

**my code to recieve the request** (the breakpoint applied is not being hit)

```
    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]Class1 value)
    {

    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put([FromBody]Class1 value)
    {
    }
```

Comment: What's the definition of `Class2`?

Comment: Hi I've added the definition of class two, why could that have made a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve the issue thanks to the advice from [this link - Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhenInDoubtTurnOnTracing.aspx)

My sending project and receiving project had identical classes (including data annotations). Removing the annotations from the class in the receiving project resolved the binding issue but I still needed validation on the properties. Also changing the annotation from required to Range also resolved the binding issue (I only mention these as they were some steps I took to try and debug).

The final solution for me was to change this

```
public class Network
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "NetworkID is required")]
    public int NetworkID { get; set; }
}
```

to this

```
[DataContract]
public class Network
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int NetworkID { get; set; }
}
```